# PHP include file extensions?

Tags: php, include, require, file-extension

For required/included files in PHP, is it better to use `.inc` extensions vs `.inc.php` vs `.php` extensions?

Comment: i was wondering in terms of processing / load - are `inc` files processed differently?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sometimes people use the `.inc` extension and then do some server configuration to keep `.inc` files from being accessed via a web browser. This *might* be good, if done absolutely correctly by a knowledgeable sysadmin, but there's a better way: Any file that's not supposed to be accessed by web users should be kept outside your document root. Once these files are off the web, so to speak, you can use whatever extension you want. `.php` is definitely a sensible choice for syntax highlighting, general sanity, and so on.

Comment: what about putting the .inc file in the directory above `public_html`?

Comment: No problem, if you want to do that. But using the `.inc` extension breaks the natural file association for no good reason. (There is no performance benefit, as your comment above asks.)

Answer (score 1):

Apache can sometimes (due to bugs or severe crashes) serve .php files as text (happend to me a few times on shared hosting).... I think you can use any extension you want as long as you don't store your files in a public folder.

Let's say your site is in /home/user/public_html/

create another folder /home/user/lib_php/

 have the files:

(1) .../lib_php/one.class.php with

```
class one { 
//...
}
```

(2) .../lib_php/two.function.php with

```
function two() { 
//...
}
```

and you have the main index.php in /public_html 

`<?php 
include_once('../lib_php/one.class.php');
include_once('../lib_php/two.function.php');`

$x=a;
$b=two($x);
$c=new one;
//etc..

or

```
 
<?php
require_once('/home/user/lib_php/the.file.php');
```

This way you are taking every precaution the files are not reachable directly but can be used by your scripts...

Comment: I usually put functions in static classes and use an __autoload() function. That way i don't need to bother with includes and the speed loss is minor compared to the time you save by not having to remember include paths (or finding typos).

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is that anything in the document root is a .php file, to indicate it's directly executable by the web server, and anything that's a library is a .inc file stored in a parallel directory, to indicate it's NOT directly executable.

My standard configuration is

`/home/sites/example.com/html/` - anything here is 'safe' to expose if PHP fails and serves up raw code

`/home/sites/example.com/inc/` - libraries, config files with passwords (e.g. the database connection class with DB credentials), etc.. Anything that shouldn't be exposed as there's no reason for it.

While you can certainly configure Apache to deny access to .inc files and keep them inside the webroot, then you're depending on Apache to keep you safe. If PHP can fail within Apache and expose your code, then the .inc blocks can ALSO fail and expose your code's innards as well.

Of course, if Apache's coughing blood all over the floor, there's no reason that the directory traversal protection can't fail as well and let someone do http://example.com/../inc/seekritpasswords.txt.

At some point you just have to accept that if something's stored anywhere on the web server, there's a possibility that a failure may allow access to the raw data and expose everything. How much time and effort you want to expend on protecting against that is up to you.