# Is the php file extension needed for importation?

Tags: php, include

I wonder if I need to use ".php" for the php snippet files I must include in my principal page with `include_once(...)`. When included in my code those snippets are handled as php instructions I guess so, then can we avoid the extension (snippets are in a folder named 'php' so no confusions).

Anyway isn't that going to make serious disturbances within my code ?

Comment: It just confuses people (and some editors) if you don't name your PHP files properly...

Comment: take a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391235/php-include-file-extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to use ".php" extension for "include_once()" or "include()". You may use any extension like may be .txt or .inc. The point to note that any PHP code in the included file is enclosed in the PHP tag, otherwise it will be treated as HTML.

Another point to consider is to not keep sensitive information in the included files (mainly if you choose to give them a non-.php extension) to prevent them being accessed on the browser. Or keep those files outside your document root.

Comment: but if the code within the included files are not enclosed in PHP tags, won't them be treated as PHP (even though they are plain text) regarding the tags used to call the include function though ? I'm a bit confused ..anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: No, if the code isn't included in the PHP tags, it is not treated as PHP disregard whatever be the extension of your script file. In other words, if the extension of the file is .php, but your code isn't enclosed in PHP tags, it is not treated as PHP code.

The PHP tags apply only to the script they are placed in. Thus tags used to call the include_once does not affect the code included from other files that should have their own PHP enclosing tags.

The PHP interpreter when executing the file switches to PHP mode on encountering the <?php tag and HTML mode when encountering the ?> tag

Comment: ok this is clear thanks, then if it's just for including common metadatas for all the pages in my website I'm free to use whether the .php extension or not, the text will be included as plain text regardless to the extension given to the files ? just verifying I'm right :p

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the file extension from your include files and didn't setup your webserver accordingly, those includes can be viewed as regular text files as they're not interpreted by PHP (if the're within the web root)