# Want some information about .inc files

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is .inc and why to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129842/what-is-inc-and-why-to-use-it)

I am working on a project which is partially developed by someone else. He has defined some inc files and some funcitons inside the files. Now i need to use those functions. For that, i need to know the below details. I tried some links by googling it. But i still can't get clear idea. My doubts are,

> 1) what is .inc file?
>
> 2) Is there any difference between .inc file and .php file?
>
> 3) How to include an inc file inside a php file?
>
> 4) How to access the functions defined in .inc file inside php file?

Anyone help me by providing the details.

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/163021/diffrence-between-inc-and-php-file

Comment: @Venu I saw that question before i posted. It doesn't have relevant information and also doesn't have any code example.

Comment: Well, It doesn't show show up your research effort. If you had seen it earlier, you should have mentioned in your question and explain us which you didn't understand.

Comment: @Venu See my post. I have mentioned clearly that i tried some links but i still can't get clear idea. So i decided to post here by expecting some clear answers

Comment: @Edwin Alex, I would love to see some links which you have read. Anyway, hope you get answers here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. An inc file is just a file that contains some stuff (functions, classes, constants) that you want to be able to include in other files.
2. There is no difference between an inc file and a php file, except that unless specifically configured to do so, your server won't execute the php in an inc file unless it is included in a php file.
3. You can include the file like this:

   include "directory/file.inc";
4. Once you've included the file, you can consider its content to be part of the file you are in, so you can access the contents as you would if they were in your file.

Note: There is no special meaning to the .inc extension - you could call it a .bunnyrabbit file, and it would work exactly the same.

Comment: bunnyrabbit extension. Sounds nice.

Comment: Thanks man. It is really helpful for me. Now i understood the concept. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**.inc - Include File**

Text file containing declarations, headers, functions, or other data referenced by a program's source code; can be used with C/C++, Pascal, Java, PHP (Web pages), and other languages.

INC files help make programming more efficient because one file can be referenced by many other files instead of having to rewrite the code multiple times.

**you can include it as simply as includes php file**

for more info

[PHP include file extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391235/php-include-file-extensions)

[what is the difference between .php and .php.inc file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938916/what-is-the-difference-between-php-and-php-inc-file-extension)

http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/inc

Answer (score 0):

1. [what is .inc file?](https://www.google.lv/search?q=what%20is%20.inc%20file)
2. [Is there any difference between .inc file and .php file?](https://www.google.lv/search?q=Is%20there%20any%20difference%20between%20.inc%20file%20and%20.php%20file)
3. [How to include an inc file inside a php file?](https://www.google.lv/search?q=How%20to%20include%20an%20inc%20file%20inside%20a%20php%20file)
4. [How to access the functions defined in .inc file inside php file?](https://www.google.lv/search?q=How%20to%20access%20the%20functions%20defined%20in%20.inc%20file%20inside%20php%20file)

Was that so hard?

Comment: It is not so hard to get irrelevant information in google. I googled it. But i didnt get what i want. That's why i posted here.

Comment: Then learn to read google. All your answers are there.

Comment: No.. it is not there. Try the last link what you have given. Is that the answer for my question?

Comment: Well, if the 4th question is not answered in google, then why didnt you ask just one question instead of 4?

Answer (score 0):

It is just another extension file.
Just for references he set it up as .inc ( most probably .include )

It has some disadvantages as servers are not configured to treat those file so anyone can actually see the source code of those files.
It would be wiser to turn them into .php files and adding them into an includes folder.

There are no other difference between them and you you can access them as a normal php file.

To define them, you can simple include("file.inc") and use the methods that are provided in there